# 70's YA scifi novel by a Dutch-named author, with a levitating(?) boy abducted or visiting a small ball-shaped spaceship

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

In the 70's I read a young adult novel where a boy was levitating and/or shortly abducted and/or visiting a small ball-shaped spaceship. I recall the writer was Dutch or Dutch-named. The feeling in the book was quite natural and non-scifi.

Comment: Dutch-named? Possibly A.E.van Vogt? http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/v/a-e-van-vogt/

Comment: A possibility: Gertrude Friedberg's 'The Revolving Boy'.